# 10 jqgrid with tabs

Tags: asp.net, jqgrid

I have 10 pages, each with a jqgrid, and a separate master page. In the master page I use jquery tabs and divs to specify the jqgrid in each page. Everything works fine apart, except that all the pages are loading when the application starts. What I want is for them to load individually whenever a user clicks on a tab. The grid should then load and display the result. I've tried with div onclick (which specifes the page and tab too) but that doesn't work.

Comment: Please change format of your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jqGrid has parameter [datatype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) which can be changed any time. You can set initially `datatype:'local'` to all jqGrids which you has in all tabs. Such grids will ignore the `url` parameter and don't send any requests to the server. In the selected tab you can change the [datatype](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) to 'json' or 'xml' depend on your server part

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'json'});
```

For the previous selected tab you can optionally set

```
$('#list').jqGrid('setGridParam',{datatype:'local'});
```

but it is probably not really needed. Moreover you can additionally consider to refresh the grid contain with `$('#list').trigger('reloadGrid')` (if it is good for your scenario).

Comment: Actually my requirement is different than wat u have said. But any how thanks for the response. And i used this methods and it also helped me